# Model classes are not listed when "a controller using Entity Framework" is added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC test project. I decided to isolate my DataLayer from the main project.

I added another project to my solution. I created all my model classes (public access modifier). Then I created my context class so `DbContext` can make relationships with my models.

Then, I created my repositories using interfaces and implemented them. I used Entity Framework to do migrations. Finally, I could create my code-first database in SQL Server.

Now, I want to add an admin area to my main project. After adding, I decided to add controllers using Entity Framework. But it doesn't list my DataLayer and its model classes in the list. All the classes I've made have a namespace of "DataLayer". I searched StackOverFlow and found a similar question but the answers did not solve my problem.

How can I fix this?

My solution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can manually type it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I referenced the first project in the second project.